# A corollary of Niven

Tags: systems-of-equations, quaternions, division-algebras

Please proof corollary of Niven: For $a \in D\backslash R$, the equation ${t^n} = a$ has exactly $n$ solutions in $D$, all of which lie in $R\left( a \right)$, in there $R$ is a real-closed field and $D$ ia the division ring of quaternions over $R$ . Thank all.

Comment: It is a bit unclear to me what is assumed and what is claimed? Can we assume that $R$ is real closed, and $D/R$ is a division ring of quaternions over $R$? And the we are to prove that $t^n=a$ has $n$ solutions in $D$, all of which are in $R(a)$?

Comment: OK. Can you hlep me prove this stament? Please.